# Want to print the loop of json object But can't access value from json object

Tags: javascript, php, json, ajax, loops

When I echo in my php code `json_encode($state);` it will show the data in these format in console

```
{"branchid":"71","branchareaid":"4","branchname":"Zaidy","branchno":"11","branchnamearabic":"\u0625\u064a\u0645\u064a \u0632\u064a\u062f\u064a","branchaddress":"Unnamed Road, Al Hamra and Umm Al Jud, Makkah 24331, Saudi Arabia","branchlat":"21.38958330","branchlong":"39.70306130","branchstatus":"1","mobileno":"0566689175","googlemaplink":"https:\/\/goo.gl\/maps\/rK3oKf1wfVu","workingHours":"6 am to 3 am"}
```

JSON object has both side curly braces with comma separated when I want to print in my ajax code through the loop it gives error and not printing the values in li

```
<?php
include "admin/includes/dbconnection.php"; 
if($_POST){
    $state =  $_POST['state'];

}else{
    $state = 1;
}

?>

<?php 
$query = "SELECT * FROM branches WHERE branchareaid = {$state}";
$res = mysqli_query($conn,$query);
while($state = mysqli_fetch_assoc($res)){
    echo json_encode($state);

}
?>
```

This is my ajax code who fetch record but the loop is not printing values of the JSON object

```
$(document).ready(function(){
        var url = "ajax-states.php";
        $("#state").change(function(){
            $.ajax({
                type: "POST",
                data: {state: $('#state').val()},
                url: url, 
                success: function(result){
                    $("#result").html(result);
                    console.log(result);
                    //var c=0;
                    $.each( result, function( index, branch) {
                        //var state = states[c];
                        $('.locations').append("<li>"+branch.branchname+"</li>");
                        c++;
                    });
                }
            });
        });
    });





jquery.min.js:2 Uncaught TypeError: Cannot use 'in' operator to search for 'length' in 
{"branchid":"71","branchareaid":"4","branchname":"Zaidy","branchno":"11","branchnamearabic":"\u0625\u064a\u0645\u064a \u0632\u064a\u062f\u064a","branchaddress":"Unnamed Road, Al Hamra and Umm Al Jud, Makkah 24331, Saudi Arabia","branchlat":"21.38958330","branchlong":"39.70306130","branchstatus":"1","mobileno":"0566689175","googlemaplink":"https:\/\/goo.gl\/maps\/rK3oKf1wfVu","workingHours":"6 am to 3 am"}
    at C (jquery.min.js:2)
    at Function.each (jquery.min.js:2)
    at Object.success (new-find-a-store.php:553)
    at u (jquery.min.js:2)
    at Object.fireWith [as resolveWith] (jquery.min.js:2)
    at k (jquery.min.js:2)
    at XMLHttpRequest.<anonymous> (jquery.min.js:2)
```

Comment: why do you use .each? because you can catch that value like this result.branchname

Comment: @Zeljka he/she uses .each because the JSON sample she pasted is not the full http response body, it's just an example of a single item of the array she wants to receive from the ajax request

Comment: @Vincent I think that you are wrong mysqli_fetch_assoc returns only one row, and you can see in his code that console.log is before .each loop. So that means he can use just result.branchname

Comment: @Zeljka "mysqli_fetch_assoc returns only one row" => no, mysqli_fetch_assoc is called for each row in the while loop (while there are more results), see the docs if needed: https://www.php.net/manual/en/mysqli-result.fetch-assoc.php. "you can see in his code that console.log is before .each loop" => yes console.log is before .each, but the provided code is not provided by the javascript console.log, but by the json_encode($state) from the PHP side (as stated by the author), so that string is definitely printed in the http response for each row

Answer (score 0):

As I see, you are trying to iterate over an object like it was a list, that code seems to not work. One aproach could be the following:

1. Declare a variable to store the list of keys of your object, witch is a dictionary
2. iterate throw this list, and select the value of the object based on that item of the list of keys.

```
var listOfKeys = (Object.keys(result));

for (var i = 0; i < Object.keys(result).length; i++) {

      $('.locations').append("<li>"+result[listOfKeys[i]]+"</li>");

  }
```

If you would like to use any specific property of the object just:

```
  $('.locations').append("<li>"+result.nameOfTheProperty+"</li>");
```

Answer (score 0):

```
When i implement this code $.each(JSON.parse(result),function( index, branch) {
it shows the error


VM1962:2 Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token { in JSON at position 409
    at JSON.parse (<anonymous>)
    at Object.success (new-find-a-store.php:559)
    at u (jquery.min.js:2)
    at Object.fireWith [as resolveWith] (jquery.min.js:2)
    at k (jquery.min.js:2)
    at XMLHttpRequest.<anonymous> (jquery.min.js:2)
```

Comment: Yes, it's normal that you have this error because there are 2 things to fix in your code and you have fixed only one. Please look at my previous answer where I said "PS: this code might be wrong", this is the 2nd thing you have to fix but you didn't do it yet. I told you you will have this error. So what you need to do is print "[" before the while PHP loop, then print "," after each "echo json_encode($state);" then print "]" after your while loop. Do this and it will be ok :) I'm the only one that understood your issue, other people voted my answer down, but it's the right one :)

Comment: Basically your PHP code prints something like {"branchid":"71",...}{"branchid":"72",...}{"branchid":"73",...} but this is not a valid JSON string. Your code needs to return [{"branchid":"71",...},{"branchid":"72",...},{"branchid":"73",...}] with a "[" at the start, a "," after each item, and a "]" at the end. That will be valid JSON.

Answer (score 0):

`$.each()`:

- when you parse JSON then `function (key, value)`
- when you parse Array then `function (index, value)`

[From documentation](https://api.jquery.com/jquery.each/)

```js
var result = {"branchid":"71","branchareaid":"4","branchname":"Zaidy","branchno":"11","branchnamearabic":"\u0625\u064a\u0645\u064a \u0632\u064a\u062f\u064a","branchaddress":"Unnamed Road, Al Hamra and Umm Al Jud, Makkah 24331, Saudi Arabia","branchlat":"21.38958330","branchlong":"39.70306130","branchstatus":"1","mobileno":"0566689175","googlemaplink":"https:\/\/goo.gl\/maps\/rK3oKf1wfVu","workingHours":"6 am to 3 am"};
$.each( result, function( key, value) {
                        $('.locations').append("<li>"+key+" : "+ value + "</li>");
                    });
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="locations"></div>
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem is at php fix this:

```
$data=array();
while($state = mysqli_fetch_assoc($res)){
    $data[]=$state;
}
echo json_encode($data);
```

Answer (score -1):

The first parameter of `$.each()` must be an array, and you're passing `result`, which is a string.

Convert your JSON string to an array using `$.each( JSON.parse(result), ...` and it will be ok.

Explanaion: on PHP side, you converted the array to a json sring using json_encode, so you have to decode it in your javascript before using it.

PS: this code might be wrong:

```
while($state = mysqli_fetch_assoc($res)){
    echo json_encode($state);

}
```

Because when looping, it will create an output like this:

```
{"branchid":"1","branchareaid":"1"}
{"branchid":"2","branchareaid":"2"}
{"branchid":"3","branchareaid":"3"}
{"branchid":"4","branchareaid":"4"}
```

Which is not the valid JSON string for an array

A valid JSON string for an array would be:

```
[
   {"branchid":"1","branchareaid":"1"},
   {"branchid":"2","branchareaid":"2"},
   {"branchid":"3","branchareaid":"3"},
   {"branchid":"4","branchareaid":"4"}
]
```